# Combine 2 JSON files into 1 file in Node or Python (i.e. longitude and latitude)

Tags: python, node.js

I want to append the longitude to a latitude stored in 2 separated json files

The result should be stored in a 3rd file

How can I do that on Python OR Javascript/Node?

Many thanks for your support,

### LATITUDE

```
{
    "tags": [{
        "name": "LATITUDE_deg",
        "results": [{
            "groups": [{
                "name": "type",
                "type": "number"
            }],
            "values": [
                [1123306773000, 46.9976859318, 3],
                [1123306774000, 46.9976859319, 3]
            ],
            "attributes": {
                "customer": ["Acme"],
                "host": ["server1"]
            }
        }],
        "stats": {
            "rawCount": 2
        }
    }]
}
```

### LONGITUDE

```
{
    "tags": [{
        "name": "LONGITUDE_deg",
        "results": [{
            "groups": [{
                "name": "type",
                "type": "number"
            }],
            "values": [
                [1123306773000, 36.9976859318, 3],
                [1123306774000, 36.9976859317, 3]
            ],
            "attributes": {
                "customer": ["Acme"],
                "host": ["server1"]
            }
        }],
        "stats": {
            "rawCount": 2
        }
    }]
}
```

### Expected result: LATITUDE_AND_LONGITUDE

```
{
    "tags": [{
        "name": "LATITUDE_AND_LONGITUDE_deg",
        "results": [{
            "groups": [{
                "name": "type",
                "type": "number"
            }],
            "values": [
                [1123306773000, 46.9976859318, 36.9976859318, 3],
                [1123306774000, 46.9976859319, 36.9976859317, 3]
            ],
            "attributes": {
                "customer": ["Acme"],
                "host": ["server1"]
            }
        }],
        "stats": {
            "rawCount": 2
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: Do you need other keys in final JSON output? Like `groups`, `attributes`, `stats`? In your `values` list, do you need exact position of latitude/longitude (should they appear as second and third element in the list)? What is the first element in `values` list (`1123306773000` and `1123306774000`)?

Comment: Yes I want all keys, yes the list is exact position of lat/long and yes, the first element is 1123306773000 but I have 30 files to convert

Answer (score -1):

I have written the solution with a colleague, find the source code on github: https://gist.github.com/Abdelkrim/715eb222cc318219196c8be293c233bf